# Sorting Object by sub-object property

Tags: javascript

I have an object of objects, which I'd like to sort by property... having some trouble wrapping my head around it:

```
sample = {
    "Elem1": { title: "Developer", age: 33 },
    "Elem2": { title: "Accountant", age: 24 },
    "Elem3": { title: "Manager", age: 53 },
    "Elem4": { title: "Intern", age: 18}
}
```

My expected result would be an object whose keys were now ordered Elem4, Elem2, Elem1, Elem3. Alternatively, I'd be fine with simply returning the keys in that order rather than physically sorting the object.

Is this more trouble than it's worth, or am I missing some obvious (or not-so-obvious) JavaScript-Fu that would make light work of something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties (keys) of an object are not intrinsically ordered; you must maintain your own array of their ordering if you wish to do so.

Here is an example of how you could simplify ordering your sample object by arbitrary properties via custom sort functions:

```
var orderKeys = function(o, f) {
  var os=[], ks=[], i;
  for (i in o) {
    os.push([i, o[i]]);
  }
  os.sort(function(a,b){return f(a[1],b[1]);});
  for (i=0; i<os.length; i++) {
    ks.push(os[i][0]);
  }
  return ks;
};

orderKeys(sample, function(a, b) {
  return a.age - b.age;
}); // => ["Elem4", "Elem2", "Elem1", "Elem3"]

orderKeys(sample, function(a, b) {
  return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
}); // => ["Elem2", "Elem1", "Elem4", "Elem3"]
```

Once the properties are ordered as you like then you can iterate them and retrieve the corresponding values in order.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, and I greatly appreciate the code sample!

Answer (score 2):

An `Object` in JavaScript has no order for properties; they may come in any order when iterated over (though in practice they *usually* come in the order they are defined).

Use an `Array`, which has an explicit order, and the `sort()` method.

If it were an `Array`, you could use...

```
sample.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/bFtzX/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't sort a hashmap.  : )

However, here is a very simple sort, if you had an actual array.

```
var sample = [{title:'Developer', age:33}, ...  etc  ];

function ageSorter(a,b)
{
   return ((a.age) < (b.age)) ? 1 : -1;
}

sample.sort(ageSorter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Searched for the same. maerics anwser is working but when i move the compare function into the new sort function it will be easier to use (in most cases).
Also this version does not break if you added something to the object prototype.

```
function subObjSortKeys(o,k,f)
{
 let keys=[],opa=[],i;
 for(i in o) if(o.hasOwnProperty(i)) keys.push([i,o[i]]);
 if(!f) f=isNaN(keys[0][1][k])?((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)):((a,b)=>a-b);
 keys.sort((a,b)=> f(a[1][k],b[1][k]));
 for(i=0; i<keys.length; i++) opa.push(keys[i][0]);
 return opa;
}

console.log(subObjSortKeys(sample, 'age'));
console.log(subObjSortKeys(sample, 'title'));
```